# Xamarin.Android: Widget doesn't update

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, widget, android-widget

I created a widget with a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/simplewidget/) in C# and Xamarin. The problem is, that the Widget doesn't update. 
I uploaded the code the a [Github repo](https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin), so you can easily see the code.
In the [`appwidgetprovider.xml`](https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin/blob/main/Resources/xml/appwidgetprovider.xml), I set the `updatePeriodMillis` low, but this doesnt do anything.
[`widget.xml`](https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin/blob/main/Resources/layout/widget.xml) is the Layout for the Widget. 
[`AppWidget.cs`](https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin/blob/main/AppWidget.cs) starts a service for the widget. 
[`UpdateService.cs`](https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin/blob/main/UpdateService.cs) uses a remoteView to set the text in the Widget, the Problem, is it doesn't happen 
Sometimes when I am pushing the App with the Debugger through VS 2019, the Widget suddenly works, but then I update something else, it suddenly doesnt work anymore, which frankly doesnt make any sense to me. Maybe I build a critical mistake into the code, but I dont see any

Comment: I tested the code on GitHub. The widget could be added into the device screen. Could not reproduce your issue. Could you provide more details for me?

Comment: Yes, the Widget can be added to the screen, but it doesn't get updated. It just says the default text "Placeholder" and not the temperature

Comment: I could not load the data and the app needs me to ask something from developers. The Widget gets the default value "Placeholder" from the app controls. Have you load the data well?

Comment: There should be a nopaste link with the error log. Sometimes the data loads

Comment: yes, i saw the link. But the link does not work for me. I could not open the link.

Comment: Yes, I couldnt figure out how to make a clickable link in a alert, without custom view

Comment: You could try to add a textview with hyperlink in alert dialog.

Comment: yeah, but then i would have to create a custom view which i dont want to

Comment: But if you want to use the hyperlink, to create a custom view is a good choice.

Comment: I fixed this, by removing the bitmap from internet thing